# How can I to create line graph with different datas?

Tags: powerbi

I have two different datas and I would like to create a line graph using one column of each data. (Three lines, two lines by type value (Old and New) and one column from value A.  I couldn't to use RELATED because I have a column type
My datas are like this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CIu5X.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YfMGd.png)

So I thought in create two new columns in one data like third photo. How can I do it? But I accepted other ways!
The two data will always update, so it's necessary that the adjustment too update automatically
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yxnaZ.png)